# Exception during bulk loads do Cassandra 1.1

Tags: cassandra, bulk-load

I'm getting exception while bulk loads with sstableloader. I'm using JDK 1.6.0_25 64bit, Ubuntu 12.04 server. Ipv6 is turned off. Network communication between hosts works correctly. I'm going crazy ;-(

```
Exception in thread "Streaming to /192.168.219.36:1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.unchecked(FBUtilities.java:628)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:276)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnectionPool.newSocket(OutboundTcpConnectionPool.java:96)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.connectAttempt(FileStreamTask.java:245)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.FileStreamTask.runMayThrow(FileStreamTask.java:91)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
```

All hosts runs Cassandra 1.1 (datastax edition). Ports 7000,7199,9160 opened. Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Why are you streaming to port 1? It should be the RPC_PORT and the default for that is 9160.

> /192.168.219.36: **1**

What params are you passing to the bulkloader?